# Sometimes when I clicked on an element the "evt.type" return "mousemove" instead on "mouseup". How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-directive

Is there a case in which the following code does not execute properly?

```
app.directive('pW', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('mousedown', function (evt) {
                element.bind('mouseup mousemove', function handler(evt) {
                    if (evt.type === 'mouseup') {
                        console.log("click");
                    } else {
                        console.log("drag");
                    }
                    element.off('mouseup mousemove', handler);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In some case when I clicked the element the "evt.type" return "mousemove" instead of "mouseup".

Answer (score 0):

You're binding to both events with this: `element.bind('mouseup mousemove'`

The event handler you've passed it runs on both mouseup and mousemove events. During the "some cases" you referred to, you may have clicked but you also moved the mouse. Trust the browser, it's telling the truth.

If this is not the behavior you desire, do not bind to both events.

Unrelated - if you're attempting to implement drag and drop, this will not work. The problem is that your second event handler is bound to the draggable element, and it will *not* move as quickly as your mouse cursor. This will result in many unwanted "drops". Instead, bind an event handler on the window itself for this purpose.

Something like this (untested):

```
app.directive('pW', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('mousedown', function (evt) {
                var $win = angular.element($window);
                $win.bind('mouseup.draggable mousemove.draggable', function handler(evt) {
                    if (evt.type === 'mouseup') {
                        console.log("click");
                    } else {
                        console.log("drag");
                    }
                    $win.off('.draggable', handler);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Note that I've switched the events to be namespaced so that you're not removing *all* window event listeners for those types.

Comment: Just wanted to mention also that a `mouseup` will not indicate a `click`, as you've written in your code. You'll need to store the mouse coordinates in your mousedown handler and test for movement of the mouse against some threshold. For instance, if the mouse has moved less than 5 pixels (horizontally or vertically) from the mousedown point, a mouseup can safely be assumed to be a sloppy click (with a bit of drag). More movement would indicate the user intended to drag the element. Test and determine a good threshold for your users.

Comment: As mentioned, this is untested and may not do what you want it to do. It is meant as a reference, not for copying and pasting. Maybe explaining what "not working" means would be more helpful. If you're having a tough time with this, you should probably just use an existing library for drag and drop, there are many. You're going to have several challenges in creating your own, including viewport positioning, scroll positioning, the need for a placeholder, and cross-browser issues.